# Smoothing out glitchy javascript animation (logical issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Sorry about the slightly misleading title. I don't really know how else to word my issue.

I'm working on a website and I'm having problems with the transition between animations when rolling over these 2 icons. When you roll your mouse over either icon, the animations run just fine, but when you move it over the next icon, you can see it fades out and fades back in immediately. It just looks bad.

You can see the issue for yourself here: http://theromdepot.com/

Now to correct this, I tried checking if either of the images are currently hovered when leaving the icon, and if not, go ahead and return everything to normal. If either of them were currently hovered, then only change the text and don't fade anything. For some reason, I couldn't get it to work no matter what I did and scrapped the whole thing. If anybody could come up with a solution, I'd be very grateful.

Here's the related javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cartridge").hover(function(){
        document.getElementById("archivetext").innerHTML = "View The Archive";  
        $("#archivetext").animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
        $("#slogan").animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
        $("#recent").animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
        $("#cartridge").animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    }, function(){
        $("#cartridge").animate({opacity: .9}, 200);
        $("#archivetext").animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
        $("#slogan").animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
        $("#recent").animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    });

    $("#manual").hover(function(){
        document.getElementById("archivetext").innerHTML = "View The Manuals";
        $("#archivetext").animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
        $("#slogan").animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
        $("#recent").animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
        $("#manual").animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    }, function(){
        $("#manual").animate({opacity: .9}, 200);
        $("#archivetext").animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
        $("#slogan").animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
        $("#recent").animate({opacity: 1}, 400);

    });
});
```

Just in case, here's a link to the whole source code: http://pastebin.com/di5kcZ6N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. You have to call it before every `.animate()` call, like so:

```js
$("#archivetext").stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
```

Same goes for the `.animate()` calls you didn't include here, but are present in your pastebin.

```js
$(".Cartridge").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "+=20", width: "+=20"}, 200);
});
$(".Cartridge").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "-=20", width: "-=20"}, 200);
});
```

By the way, if you use increments/decrements with `.animate()`, you may have strange side effects when mousing in and out fast, so it's best if you use absolute values, like:

```js
$(".Cartridge").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: 300, width: 300}, 200);
});
$(".Cartridge").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: 280, width: 280}, 200);
});
```

And while you're at it, take this and incorporate it to the part of the script you posted, so you'll have all the animation behavior in one place:

```js
$("#cartridge").hover(function(){
    document.getElementById("archivetext").innerHTML = "View The Archive";  
    $("#archivetext").stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    $("#slogan").stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
    $("#recent").stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
    $("#cartridge").stop().animate({opacity: 1, height: 300, width: 300}, 200);
}, function(){
    $("#cartridge").stop().animate({opacity: .9, height: 280, width: 280}, 200);
    $("#archivetext").stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
    $("#slogan").stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    $("#recent").stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
});
```

Comment: Wow, you're awesome! Thank you so much. That'll fix a lot of problems with my page.

Comment: Sorry, one last question. When I run the mouse over each icon quickly, it keeps playing over and over. If I add .stop(), it'll stop resizing the icon they start becoming the wrong size. Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: To fix it, you should use absolute values instead of increments. I've updated my answer to include that information, check it out.

Comment: Great! It definitely smooths out the effect a bunch. If I do it a bunch, it'll still animates even when my cursor is not over it? Anyway to stop that? And sorry for all the questions, I've just had this problem for the longest time and I'm glad I finally found somebody who can help

Comment: Try to incorporate all of the animation behavior in one place. So instead of having `$(".Cartridge").mouseover(...`, take that out and use `$("#cartridge").stop().animate({opacity: 1, height: 300, width: 300}, 200);`. I did this in my environment and it worked fine.

Comment: Again, you're the best! You taught me a lot and I'll put that knowledge to good use. Thank you